# Filter baseaded in .state ID field in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Filter baseaded in .state ID field.

I have this state:

```
   .state("nhaac.ofertas_restaurante", {
    url: "/ofertas_restaurante/:cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor",
    cache:false,
    views: {
        "nhaac-side_menus" : {
                    templateUrl:"templates/ofertas_restaurante.html",
                    controller: "restaurantePromocoesCtrl"
                },
```

Where I get an ID from a Json file (or Object array).

And I want get this field ID and filter in a View, listing only registers that contain the ID from the state:

```
ng-repeat="item in ofertass | filter:????????"
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the dynamic variable of your state url with $stateParams in your controller. In this case its $stateParams.***cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor*** since you've declared the state url to be /ofertas_restaurante/***:cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor***. Use this to create a custom filter where you're matching the ids.

**Controller**

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    filterById: function(item) {
      return item.cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor === $stateParams.cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor;
    }
  });
});
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ofertass | filter:filterById(item)"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, great!